# Lifting from Either to IO

Tags: haskell, monads

I would like to convert from Either monad into IO without any clues from Either. Is there more elegant way to do it?

I have written this function, but I would like to use something from a library or Prelude:

```
liftEither :: forall t (m :: * -> *) a. Monad m => (t -> m a) -> Either String t -> m a
liftEither f (Right a)  = f a
liftEither _ (Left msg) = fail msg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this using the `either` function from `Data.Either`:

```
liftEither :: Monad m => (t -> m a) -> Either String t -> m a
liftEither f xs = either fail f xs
```

Or even simpler:

```
liftEither :: Monad m => (t -> m a) -> Either String t -> m a
liftEither = either fail
```

Comment: As an aside, I would argue that defining this function isn't even worth it, because it isn't obvious by the name what it does, and `either fail` is only 1 character longer than `liftEither`.

Comment: @user2407038 Agree with that. I would just directly use `either`. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree too! I just wrote the question as a function to be more precise. Thanks for the simplification and the answer!